# Subclipse and SVN - Errors and Login Info

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

1) I'm try to access an svn repository with a url like this: svn://asdfasd.asdfasdf.edu/asdfasdf/asdfasdf.

When I do so, I get an error stating: "Authorization Failed." I know for a fact that the url is correct. And I just redownloaded subclipse.

**How can I fix this?**

2) I also want to change my user login information. I can't find anywhere to do this (including Google). I have a new Macbook Pro with Eclipse and subclipse.

**How can I change the login data?**

EDIT:

**Really despearate for an answer on this one. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

1) You could post more error message (i.e. full copy of what is being displayed in your Eclipse console).

As it's unlikely that you've hit this kind of bug in Subclipse, for starters, please triple-check:

- the address,
- the port number,
- your credentials.

You may also try the repository address without the trailing part - like `svn://asdfasd.asdfasdf.edu/asdfasdf/` instead of `svn://asdfasd.asdfasdf.edu/asdfasdf/asdfasdf` *(not sure how SVN behaves here, but might be worth a shot)*.

Also, what kind of SVN server is that? Can you possibly connect and log in via a web browser on the same address? Some servers (VisualSVN) support this - just paste the URL into your browser and see if there's a web interface. If yes, then you can make sure there if your credentials are valid.

2) If you want to change your username/password, I believe you need to have administrative rights to the SVN server. Please contact the administrator for that.